# Space between top of page and header

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to finish my header, but there is a massive space between the top of the page and the header. I would like to keep my image in place but the header at top but the same size. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="header_logo-clearfix">
    <div id="header_logo"><a href="file:///C:/Users/Swag/Desktop/My%20Website/Home/home.html"><div id="logo"><img src="Header/banner.png" alt="Logo" align="middle" width="300"height="100"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #header_logo-clearfix {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: #02236a;
}

#header_logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er2Ljd46/).

Comment: IF you only formatted your HTML properly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `#header_logo {` has `margin-top: 40px;` Just remove it will solve your issue.

**Edit:**

Add `padding-top:40px;` instead will down your image.

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/er2Ljd46/5/)

New updated CSS:

```
#header_logo-clearfix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: #02236a;
}

#header_logo {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It made the background go up, then how do I move the image down?

Comment: Give `padding-top: 40px;`.

Comment: thanks @ketan , I'll mark it as correct in 3 minutes lol

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `<div>` tag here

```
<div id="logo"><img src="Header/banner.png" alt="Logo" align="middle" width="300"height="100">
```

The div with id "logo" does not have a corresponding end tag. I am not sure if that will fix the issue but it can definitely give you unexpected behavior in lower end browsers that are not capable of auto matching missing HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `marrgin-top: 40px` from #header_logo class

check this[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er2Ljd46/4/)

Comment: this was already answered 3 min ago...

Comment: i was not aware when he was posting the answer .... :|